# Unknown writing system: different letters or variants of the same letter?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering

In a fictitious language, there are 4 graphic variants of what is commonly believed to be the same letter "a": a1, a2, a3, a4.
In a corpus of texts, any word containing "a" (Xa, Ya, Za, etc.) can be written with different variants of "a", but there are differences in the frequencies:

```
            variant
          a1  a2  a3  a4
words Xa  12  15  0   3
      Ya  20  16  5   0
      Za  1   0   15  18
```

(NB: In my actual data, there are many more variants and many more words)

I suspect that the distribution is not random, and that all of these are not free variants of "a", so that there might be actually several distinct letters. How can I test this? And how do I determine the potential groups (which letters go together)?

Some more precisions:

- the null hypothesis is that the 4 variants are interchangeable and can be used to write any word, so that knowing the word does not allow to predict which variants will be used
- the alternative hypothesis that I want to test is whether which variant is used depends on the words
- if the choice between variants does depend on words, I would like to know which variants are interchangeable and which are not (how to group variants)
- I am also interested into knowing how words can be partionned into groups according to the variants they use

Comment: "Groups" of what?  Words or letters?

Comment: groups of letters

Comment: I think you are trying to check if the frequency of each variant, when appearing next to different letters, comes from the same multinomial probability distribution.  It's not an answer but it might give you a direction.

Comment: You need to formulate your hypothesis as a statistical one; there are logical leaps you're making there that are nothing to do with statistics but involve subject matter justification. "Distribution is not random" is not precise. "Which letters go together" is not precise. Do you mean something like "How do I test for independence/homogeneity of proportions in this contingency table?" and "Which variants are more likely to appear in which words than would be expected with independence?" ... (some additional clarification may still be needed).  ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Then you can argue from say a rejection of independence to whatever your in-subject conclusion is, using subject-matter arguments.

Comment: I have added more info

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions about what you're after, as suggested by my comment:

You can test for independence in a table like this:

```
            variant
          a1  a2  a3  a4
words Xa  12  15  0   3     
      Ya  20  16  5   0     
      Za  1   0   15  18
```

using (for example) a chi-square test.

Wikipedia [Pearson's chi-squared test: Test of independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence)

You might perhaps then look at a table of observed-expected to find those with positive residuals,

```
  + + - -
  + + - -
  - - + +
```

or perhaps look at Pearson residuals (say) to identify the "large" positive ones:

```
  . # = -
  # + - =
  = = # #
Legend: -Inf ‘=’ -1.96 ‘-’ -1 ‘.’ 1 ‘+’ 1.96 ‘#’ Inf
```

Those tables of symbols generated with Rs `symnum`. E.g. the second had:

```
symnum((a-exp)/sqrt(exp),
       cut=c(-Inf,  -1.96,  -1,  1,   1.96,  Inf),
       sym= c(   "=",    "-", ".", "+",  "#"))
```